# Proper way to index date & time columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
   ID int identity,
   Whatever varchar(100),
   MyTime time(2) NOT NULL,
   MyDate date NOT NULL,
   MyDateTime AS (DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', [MyDate]), 
                          CAST([MyDate] AS DATETIME2(2))))
)
```

The computed column adds date and time into a single datetime2 field.

Most queries against the table have one or more of the following clauses:

```
... WHERE MyDate < @filter1 and MyDate > @filter2
... ORDER BY MyDate, MyTime
... ORDER BY MyDateTime
```

In a nutshell, `date` is usually used for filtering, and full `datetime` is used for sorting.

Now for questions:

1. What is the best way to set indices on those 3 date-time columns? 2 separate on `date` and `time` or maybe 1 on `date` and 1 on composite `datetime`, or something else? Quite a lot of inserts and updates occur on this table, and I'd like to avoid over-indexing.
2. As I wrote this question, I noticed the long and kind of ugly computed column definition. I picked it up from somewhere a while ago and forgot to investigate if there's a simpler way of doing it. Is there any easier way of combining a `date` and `time2` into a `datetime2`? Simple addition does not work, and I'm not sure if I should avoid casting to `varchar`, combining and casting back.

Comment: I just have to ask the obvious: why do you need separate columns for date and time?

Comment: Had a feeling that question would pop.. It can be modified into a single datetime2 column, but often only Time part changes and a lot of queries filter by date part of it, and stripping time created issues in the past during that select (between x and y would not include y date, since time defaults to 00:00:00, and it needs to be changed to 23:59:59 to include entire day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having date and time in two separate columns may seem peculiar but if you have queries that use only the date (and/or especially only the time part), I think it's a valid decision. You can create an index on date only or on time or on (date, whatever), etc.

What I don't understand is why you also have the computed datetime column as well. There s no reason to store this value, too. It can easily be calculated when needed.

And if you need to order by datetime, you can use `ORDER BY MyDate, MyTime`. With an index on `(MyDate, MyTime)` this should be ok. Range datetime queries would also be using that index.

Comment: I added computed column simply for easier maintenance of queries, as whenever that date-time is included in SELECT clause of a query, both date and time are returned as single column. It seems to be easier to add that computed column than to add the same formula to 10+ queries, and it should do the same thing since its not persisted, no?

Comment: That sounds like a valid reason. But you don't need the persistance and indexing it. The `(MyDate, MyTime)` index would be used for the queries you have supplied. (except for the `ORDER BY MyDateTime` which should not be used)

Comment: I think I'll stick to this solution as it requires least changes, and i feel more comfortable having separate date and time columns, since strange requests for new queries are coming in from my employer on daily basis. Having values split just seems safe for now. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you didn't mention what **version** of SQL Server you're using ....

But if you're on SQL Server **2008 or newer**, you should turn this around:

your table should have

```
MyDateTime DATETIME
```

and then define the "only date" column as

```
MyDate AS CAST(MyDateTime AS DATE) PERSISTED
```

Since you make it **persisted**, it's stored along side the table data (and now calculated every time you query it), and you can easily index it now.

Same applies to the `MyTime` column.

Comment: In such a scenario would you suggest indexing only MyDateTime? Would 'PERSISTED' even be needed with an additional index on computed MyDate?

Comment: @Jeti: if you select on `MyDate` - I would create an index on `MyDate` and see if it helps. I would then also create a second, separate index on `MyDateTime` and see if that helps anything with your query. If yes - leave the index  - if no, toss it again

Comment: @Jeti: and yes - I would always try to use `PERSISTED` - even if you could technically create an index without it. If that data doesn't change 10 times every minute, it makes sense to persist the result of the calculation and re-calculate only when the "base" column's value changes.

Answer (score 1):

The answer isn't in your indexing, it's in your querying.

A single `DateTime` field should be used, or even `SmallDateTime` if that provides the range of dates and time resolution required by your application.

Index that column, then use queries like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE
    MyDate >= @startfilterdate
    AND MyDate < DATEADD(d, 1, @endfilterdate);
```

By using `<` on the end filter, it only includes results from sometime before midnight of that date, which is the day after the user-selected "end date". This is simpler and more accurate than adding 23:59:59, especially since stored times can include microseconds between 23:59:59 and 00:00:00.

Using persisted columns and indexes on them is a waste of server resources.

Comment: As posted in my comment @ypercube, i'll stick with separated columns for now, since there's a pretty good chance i'll have to filter by time component in the near future, and god knows what else if any change requests come by.